# How do you add a new user to phpBB via the command line or script?

Tags: mysql, phpbb

I have a regular users DB and a phpBB support form.
The only feature I care to integrate is making sure the a user gets added to phpBB database when they register on my regular user database.

How do I synchronously add a user to phpBB from the cli as a user registers on my regular users db?

Comment: Might Help: **[Adding a user through MySQL query](https://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=2282086&p=14467591#p14467591)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always use php, adapt and existing mod they have   https://github.com/phpbb/phpbb/blob/3.1.x/phpBB/includes/ucp/ucp_remind.php#L87-L100